# Base64 Code As Background Image Hackable?

Tags: css, image, base64

I used base64 code as a background image via CSS file. Is it possible to get hacked this way?

Comment: Why the down rate? My host thinsk because I use base64 code as a background image, the site may get hacked. I said no, but decided to ask here to be sure.

Comment: what has image to do with your website being hacked?

Comment: Hey StackOverflow community, why not be supportive?  He asked a question because he didn't know something, there's no reason to trample him with downvotes.  Perhaps try and explain your point and not be derogatory.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where does `base64` come into play? Are you using it somewhere in your code or are the images named and referred to statically? Are you passing an unsafe (user-supplied) parameter to it? Was your host any more specific about the way you may be hacked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO**, it can't be hacked because of that, your host is confused about what it is, you just have to tell them it's pretty much the same as using `url(/path/to/image.jpg);`.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks.